# Youtube video won't play on iOS6 app but works when downloaded from the App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, ios6

I have a Youtube video that was working fine in iOS 5 but now doesn't load in iOS 6. The strange thing is that if I download the app from the App Store the onto an iOS6 device the videos play fine. The problem is that if I build it on the device from XCode then the videos won't load. Same code, nothing changed. The difference is only if I build from XCode.

any idea what I might do to solve this?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [iOS6 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

> As of iOS 6, embedded YouTube URLs in the form of
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0 will no longer work. These
>   URLs are for viewing the video on the YouTube site, not for embedding
>   in web pages. Instead, the format that should be used is described in
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters.

I have had to update some of my projects so that when they run under iOS5 they use the old URL but in iOS6 they use the new URL which is basically http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0 (to use the example above).

I saw the same behaviour as you for my apps that are being sold in the store, they somehow continue to work.

EDIT:
Here are the two string I am using in one of my apps.
iOS 5

```
<iframe width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?showinfo=0&fs=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\
        ></iframe>
```

and iOS6

```
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@\" allowfullscreen type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>
```

I have tried using the same `iframe` and `shockwave` code in both and just changing out the urls but it seems to be a combination of both that works for my testing.

Comment: that's great. thanks for your help. do you know if the  http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0 url will work under iOS5 and lower?

Comment: In my experience, no. I have two different strings that I am using and I switch at runtime. I will update my answer with the two strings I use.You should look at the developers.google.com link as there are lots of different switches you can use as well.